# ItemListener getitem() doesn't return only name

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, itemlistener

I'm using an ItemListener for my radiobuttons.
I saw a lot of ItemListener functions, but mine seems to work differently.

```
...        jUserButton2.addItemListener(ffs);
}

private ItemListener ffs = new ItemListener(){
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        String user = e.getItem().toString();
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
};
```

The value it returns is "javax.swing.JRadioButton[User,445,453,49x18,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@1f2f60d,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=false,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=User]"

Shouldn't it return just the value? (in this case is "User")

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using an `ActionListener`?  A simpler solution would be to use the `actionCommand` property of event `source` (when it's a type of `JRadioButton`, which, if not set implicitly, will return the `text` of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getItem%28%29) say:

> public Object getItem()
>   Returns the item affected by the event.

The item affected is a `JRadioButton` (which is also what the console prints). This is logical correct, since the item affected is that button. Simply change the code to this:

```
String user = ((JRadioButton) e.getItem()).getName();
System.out.println(user);
```

Comment: ha, thanks a lot... Seems ((JRadioButton) e.getItem()) is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

`JRadioButton` is a `JToggleButton`. If you look into the source code, you will see that the event is fired using the protected `fireItemStateChange` method. For example, in the `javax.swing.JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel#setSelected` method you find the following code:

```
// Send ItemEvent
fireItemStateChanged(
  new ItemEvent(this,
  ItemEvent.ITEM_STATE_CHANGED,
  this,
  this.isSelected() ?  ItemEvent.SELECTED : ItemEvent.DESELECTED));
```

This means that when you receive the `ItemEvent` and call `getItem`, you will receive the `JRadioButton` (the `this` in the above code (third constructor argument)).

Calling `toString` on the radio button gives you exactly what you are seeing.

You can fix this by casting `e.getItem()` to a `JRadioButton` and call `getText()` (or whatever info you want to retrieve) on it